Can't activate a module created in odoo development environment, named 'Student management'
It shows the following error. I use odoo 16, PostgreSQL 12.19, python 3.12, PyCharm community version.
`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\f\Downloads\odoo-16.0\odoo\http.py", line 1632, in _serve_db
return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
File "C:\Users\f\Downloads\odoo-16.0\odoo\service\model.py", line 133, in retrying
result = func()
File "C:\Users\f\Downloads\odoo-16.0\odoo\http.py", line 1659, in _serve_ir_http
response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
File "C:\Users\f\Downloads\odoo-16.0\odoo\http.py", line 1863, in dispatch
result = self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
File "C:\Users\f\Downloads\odoo-16.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 154, in _dispatch
result = endpoint(**request.params)
File "C:\Users\f\Downloads\odoo-16.0\odoo\http.py", line 716, in route_wrapper
result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
File "c:\users\f\downloads\odoo-16.0\addons\web\controllers\dataset.py", line 46, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
File "c:\users\f\downloads\odoo-16.0\addons\web\controllers\dataset.py", line 33, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\f\Downloads\odoo-16.0\odoo\api.py", line 468, in call_kw
result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\f\Downloads\odoo-16.0\odoo\api.py", line 453, in _call_kw_multi
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "", line 2, in button_immediate_install
File "C:\Users\f\Downloads\odoo-16.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 74, in check_and_log
return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\f\Downloads\odoo-16.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 475, in button_immediate_install
return self._button_immediate_function(self.env.registry[self._name].button_install)
File "C:\Users\f\Downloads\odoo-16.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 599, in _button_immediate_function
registry = modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
File "", line 2, in new
File "C:\Users\f\Downloads\odoo-16.0\odoo\tools\func.py", line 87, in locked
return func(inst, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\f\Downloads\odoo-16.0\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 90, in new
odoo.modules.load_modules(registry, force_demo, status, update_module)
File "C:\Users\f\Downloads\odoo-16.0\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 488, in load_modules
processed_modules += load_marked_modules(cr, graph,
File "C:\Users\f\Downloads\odoo-16.0\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 372, in load_marked_modules
loaded, processed = load_module_graph(
File "C:\Users\f\Downloads\odoo-16.0\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 231, in load_module_graph
load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package)
File "C:\Users\f\Downloads\odoo-16.0\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 71, in load_data
tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind)
File "C:\Users\f\Downloads\odoo-16.0\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 757, in convert_file
with file_open(pathname, 'rb') as fp:
File "C:\Users\f\Downloads\odoo-16.0\odoo\tools\misc.py", line 212, in file_open
path = file_path(name, filter_ext=filter_ext, env=env)
File "C:\Users\f\Downloads\odoo-16.0\odoo\tools\misc.py", line 191, in file_path
raise FileNotFoundError("File not found: " + file_path)
FileNotFoundError: File not found: student_management\security/ir.model.access.csvviews/student_view.xml
The above server error caused the following client error:
RPC_ERROR: Odoo Server Error
RPC_ERROR
at makeErrorFromResponse (http://localhost:8015/web/assets/21-3369537/web.assets_backend.min.js:997:163)
at XMLHttpRequest. (http://localhost:8015/web/assets/21-3369537/web.assets_backend.min.js:1005:13)`
I tried to solve it by re-installing Odoo and PostgreSQL, change the version of python. Almost all required packages are installed.

Odoo fails to open a file, check if you provided the wrong file path in the manifest file
